# prevent browsing directory on apache ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have 2 identical websites, one is for production and one is for testing.

Strange difference: when I write: `http://1.2.3.4/NAME_OF_WEBSITE_DIRECTORY` in one of them, I get the list of directories and I can browse them.

But when I do the same with the other website: `http://9.8.7.6/NAME_OF_WEBSITE_DIRECTORY`, I get an error (which is what I want for both sites)

I checked /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/WEBSITE.conf and both are identical.

So what can cause that difference?

Comment: You have the `Indexes` option enabled in one and disabled in the other host. Can be done in the host configuration itself, or by using stupid `.htaccess` style files.

Comment: check the rest of apache's .conf files. just because one single .conf doesn't say anythiung about browsing options doesn't mean there aren't options ELSEWHERE enabling/disabling it.